# Laravel - Trying to get property of non-object form error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to find an error but i can't maybe someone of You can help me. This is normal form which should pass data to mysql. I add "create.blade" and it gives me this error "trying to get property of non-object". I really dont know what is wrong. Thank You for help

Routes are resource:

```
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\User;

use Carbon\Carbon;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::all();
        $dt = Carbon::today();
        $ends = $dt->addDays(30);

        return view ('users.index', ['users'=>$users, 'dt'=>$dt, 'ends'=>$ends,]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view ('users.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
      $this->validate($request, [

       'name' => 'required',
       'email' => 'required',
    ]);
    $user = new User();

     $user->name = $request->name;
     $user->email = $request->phone;


  $user->save();

    return redirect()->route('users')

                    ->with('success','Pilot dodany poprawnie');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Create view:

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'users.store','method'=>'POST')) !!}
    <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      {{ Form::label('name', 'Name', array('class' => 'pull-left labelfont')) }}
      {{ Form::text('name',null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {{ Form::label('email', 'Email', array('class' => 'pull-left labelfont')) }}
      {{ Form::email('email',null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="pull-left labelfont">Funkcja</label>
      <select class="form-control">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="pull-left labelfont">Opłata ważna do</label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Opłata">
    </div>
    <button class="btn m-b-xs btn-sm btn-primary btn-addon pull-right"> Dodaj </button>

    <!--  {{ Form::submit('Dodaj', array('class' => 'btn m-b-xs btn-sm btn-primary btn-addon pull-right')) }} -->

  </form>
  {{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: try removing the <form> opening and closing tags, the `{{ Form::open() }}` and `{{ Form::close() }}`commands does that for you

Comment: Can we get a line number and where about in the code that might be?

Comment: ok i see that problem is in dashboard template in line 145 (dashboard template  is extend for create blade): There is "<span class="hidden-sm hidden-md">{{Auth::user()->name}}</span> <b class="caret"></b>" but earlier when i didn't do create blade all was ok. How to fix it?

Comment: This issue usually caused by using `->` on something that is not a class. Idk enough or see enough to help past that.

Comment: Problem was that session life time was 1 min.... and i was unauthorized to enter blade. Solved

Answer (score 0):

Like you said in your comment. The line with `{{ Auth::user()->name }}` crashes. That means that you are not logged in. Try to do that.

If you want to show the create form (and the navigation with that line) also when the user isn't logged in, change the code to the following:

```
@if(Auth::check())
    <span class="hidden-sm hidden-md">{{Auth::user()->name}}</span> <b class="caret"></b>
@endif
```

Or something that fits your design properly.